# Hibernate native query optional parameter throws 'operator does not exist: bigint = bytea'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE (:param IS NULL OR id_or_smth = :param)
```

The `param` parameter is optional, therefore it can be `null`

1. I createed a `javax.persistance.Query`
2. To which I then `setParameter("param", null)`
3. And when I called `getResultList()` I got the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR:
>   operator does not exist: bigint = bytea

how can i handle this?

Comment: do you really want to fetch all records of the table when param is null?

Comment: blah, in javadoc i've found that second parameter in setParameter function must be non-null.

Comment: Workaround is that you can set some default pattern when parameter is null and put that in the equal.

Comment: deterministicFail : all i was trying to simplify my query : searching if passed param is not null. but it seems won't go this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL and Criteria can only work when you specify an actual Entity property/Table column, so this doesn't work:

```
:param IS NULL
```

If id_or_smth is a Table1 column, then this is how your query should look like:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id_or_smth IS NULL or id_or_smth = :param");
q.setParameter("param", paramValye);
q.getResultList();
```

And paramValue must not be null.

In SQL, you must always use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` because a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id_or_smth = NULL
```

will always return an empty result, even if there are rows satisfying id_or_smth IS NULL

Comment: ok then. is there any Object I can pass which refer to NULL in sql? sql.Types.NULL does not work. i just dont want to change query but pass NULL somehow :)

Comment: ow wait. i didnt spot ...WHERE id_of_somth IS NULL... all I want is to search by column id_of_smth only when passed :param is not null

Comment: IS(NOT) NULL is the SQL construct you are looking for. Passing null won't work even in JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [criteria queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) instead:

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Table1.class);
crit.setProjection(Restrictions.id());
if (param != null) crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id_or_smth", param));

List result = crit.list();
```