# How to solve typecast error (operator does not exist: bigint = bytea)?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to migrate a Spring Boot application that was working fine on Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL. However, after cleaning up the queries to match the syntax of PGSQL, I am getting an error that says:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 868
```

The issue is that I have over 40 controllers and used the same pattern to code them, they are all working fine on SQL Server, but on migration to PostgreSQL, 3 out of the 40 controllers are throwing this funny error. I am passing the request as a `Long` to the controller, and the column in my database is also a `Long` (`bigint`). So I don't know where this is coming from. I have done a lot of googling but did not get the problem solved. Here are some valuable links I checked.

- [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280595/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-operator-does-not-exist-integer-byt)
- [Postgres bytea error when binding null to prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865149/postgres-bytea-error-when-binding-null-to-prepared-statements)
- [Hibernate native query optional parameter throws 'operator does not exist: bigint = bytea'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360336/hibernate-native-query-optional-parameter-throws-operator-does-not-exist-bigin)
- ... and lots more.

Here is one of the controllers:

```
    @PostMapping("/date-sum")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> sumRecordsWithDate(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

        Long type = searcherDto.getCompanyTypeId();
        Long process = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk();
        Long process1 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk1();
        Long process2 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk2();
        Long process3 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk3();
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getStartDate()), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getEndDate()), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));


        SumInterface sumInterface = sumRepository
                .sumWithDate(process, process1, process2,
                        process3, type, start, end);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", sumInterface));
    }
```

Here is the request I am sending from postman:

```json
{
"startDate": "2014-06-11",
"endDate": "2020-10-14",
"processTypeFk":9542,
"companyTypeId": 6995

    }
```

Below is my repository with native queries:

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT sum(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) then b.AMOUNT else null end) AS pending, " +
            " sum(case when (SUBMITTED = false OR SUBMITTED IS NULL) then b.AMOUNT else null end) AS notSubmitted, " +
            " sum(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else null end) AS submitted, " +
            " sum(b.AMOUNT) AS totalApplications, " +
            " sum(case when (IS_QUERIED = true ) then b.AMOUNT else null end) AS queried," +
            " sum(case when (APPROVED = true) then b.AMOUNT else null end) AS approved, " +
            " sum(case when (APPROVED = false) then b.AMOUNT else null end) AS notApproved " +
            " FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS a" +
            " LEFT JOIN PAYMENT_HISTORY b ON a.id=b.RECORD_ID AND b.PROCESS_TYPE_FK = a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK"+
            " LEFT JOIN COMPANY c ON c.id= a.COMPANY_FK " +
            " WHERE (a.FINANCIAL_YEAR_END >=:startDate AND a.FINANCIAL_YEAR_END <=:endDate) AND " +
            " b.PAYMENT_STATUS='APPROVED' AND (c.COMPANY_TYPE_FK=:companyTypeId OR :companyTypeId=0) " +
            " AND (a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK =:processTypeFk OR " +
            "(:processTypeFk1=9542 AND :processTypeFk2=9594 AND :processTypeFk3=9598)) ", nativeQuery = true)
    SumInterface sumWithDate(@Param("processTypeFk")Long processTypeFk,
@Param("processTypeFk1")Long processTypeFk1, @Param("processTypeFk2") Long processTypeFk2, @Param("processTypeFk3") Long processTypeFk3,
@Param("companyTypeId") Long companyTypeId,
@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
@Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is another controller without a LocalDateTime parameter being passed that throws the same error:

```
    @PostMapping("/count")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> countRecords(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

        Long type = searcherDto.getCompanyTypeId();
        Long process = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk();
        Long process1 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk1();
        Long process2 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk2();
        Long process3 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk3();
        SumInterface annualReturnInterface = sumRepository
                .countReturns(process, process1, process2, process3, type);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", sumInterface));
    }

//the corresponding repository with native query is

    @Query(value = "SELECT count(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) then 1 else null end) AS pending, " +
            " count(case when (SUBMITTED = false OR SUBMITTED IS NULL) then 1 else null end) AS notSubmitted, " +
            " count(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else null end) AS submitted, " +
            " count(*) AS totalApplications, " +
            " count(case when (IS_QUERIED = true) then 1 else null end) AS queried," +
            " count(case when (APPROVED = true) then 1 else null end) AS approved, " +
            " count(case when (APPROVED = false) then 1 else null end) AS notApproved " +
            " FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS a" +
            " LEFT JOIN PAYMENT_HISTORY b ON a.id=b.RECORD_ID AND b.PROCESS_TYPE_FK = a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK" +
            " LEFT JOIN COMPANY c ON c.id= a.COMPANY_FK " +
            " WHERE (c.COMPANY_TYPE_FK=:companyTypeId OR :companyTypeId=0) AND (a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK =:processTypeFk OR " +
            "(:processTypeFk1=9542 AND :processTypeFk2=9594 AND :processTypeFk3=9598)) ", nativeQuery = true)
    AnnualReturnInterface countReturn(@Param("processTypeFk") Long processTypeFk,
                                                                         @Param("processTypeFk1") Long processTypeFk1,
                                                                         @Param("processTypeFk2") Long processTypeFk2,
                                                                         @Param("processTypeFk3") Long processTypeFk3,
                                                                         @Param("companyTypeId") Long companyTypeId);
```

Below is the request am sending for this controller using postman:

```
{

"processTypeFk1": 9542,
"processTypeFk2": 9598,
"processTypeFk3": 9594,
"companyTypeId": 0

       }
```

Below is the error trace I get when I make request to both controllers:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 868
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2341) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2094) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2056) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.sumAnnualReturnByProcessTypeAndOrCompanyTypeWithDate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.sumAnnualReturnByProcessTypeAndOrCompanyTypeWithDate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.oasis.isds.executivedashboard.controller.AnnualReturnController.sumAnnualReturnRecordsWithDate(AnnualReturnController.java:94) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.oasis.isds.executivedashboard.security.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**Here are the 2 major entities**

```
//first entity

@Entity
@Table(name="ANNUAL_RETURNS")
public class AnnualReturn implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "IS_QUERIED")
    private Boolean queried;

    @Column(name = "FINANCIAL_YEAR_END")
    private String financialYearEnd;
    @Column(name = "FINANCIAL_YEAR_START")
    private String financialYearStart;

    @Column(name = "FINANCIAL_YEAR")
    private String financialYear;

    private Boolean approved;

    @Column(name = "APPROVAL_DATE")
    private Date approvalDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_FK")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROCESS_TYPE_FK",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Process_Type processType;

}

//second entity


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4358934782506546691L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "APPROVED_NAME")
    private String approvedName;

    @Column(name = "REGISTRATION_APPROVED")
    private Boolean registrationApproved;

    @Column(name = "RC_NUMBER")
    private String rcNumber;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_TYPE_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company_Type companyTypeFk;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_APPROVAL")
    private Date dateOfApproval;
```

Please help me with ideas and possible solutions.

Comment: So which of your columns is a `bytea`? (And _why_ is it one to begin with? None of the column names indicate that using `bytea` is necessary)

Comment: None of my columns is a bytea, and that is why this error is strange. The columns I am referencing are Long (bigint). In fact there's no use of a bytea in the entire application. Everything worked fine when it was on MS-SQL.   @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Then your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") is sending one of the parameters as `bytea` - maybe the LocalDateTime stuff.

Comment: I thought so too but I ran the application in debug mode to check what was being sent in the request and it was LocalDateTime and Long data types that came in during debug mode run of the app.  If you have any suggestions to solving it, I would be grateful. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue after days of brainstorming.  I discovered that the PostgreSQL driver could not handle all the abstractions in the parameter. It was seeing some as null. So what I did after trying the different suggestions and nothing worked for me was I redesigned my code and created new endpoints to handle the other levels of abstraction.

Simply put, I reduced the overloading on the repository and controller method to avoid passing nulls because MS SQL could handle that but postgreSQL could not handle it.

Here is my new repository interface method:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT count(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) 
then 1 else null end) AS pending, 
count(case when (SUBMITTED = false OR SUBMITTED IS NULL) then 1 else null end) AS notSubmitted, 
count(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else null end) AS submitted, count(*) AS totalApplications, 
count(case when (IS_QUERIED = true) then 1 else null end) AS queried, 
count(case when (APPROVED = true) then 1 else null end) AS approved, 
count(case when (APPROVED = false) then 1 else null end) AS notApproved 
FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS a LEFT JOIN PAYMENT_HISTORY b ON a.id=b.RECORD_ID 
AND b.PROCESS_TYPE_FK = a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK LEFT JOIN COMPANY c 
ON c.id= a.COMPANY_FK WHERE (c.COMPANY_TYPE_FK=:companyTypeId OR :companyTypeId=0) 
AND a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK =:processTypeFk ", nativeQuery = true)
AnnualReturnInterface countReturn(@Param("processTypeFk") Long processTypeFk,
@Param("companyTypeId") Long companyTypeId);
```

Here is the new controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/count")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> countAnnualReturnRecordsByOneProcessType
(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

        Long companyType = searcherDto.getCompanyTypeId();
        Long processType = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk();

        AnnualReturnInterface annualReturnInterface = annualReturnRepository
                .countAnnualReturnByOneProcessTypeAndCompanyType(processType, companyType);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", annualReturnInterface));
    }
```

Here is the second new repository interface method : (Note: the 2 queries were pulled out from the one in the question.)

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT count(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) 
then 1 else null end) AS pending, count(case when (SUBMITTED = false OR SUBMITTED IS NULL)
 then 1 else null end) AS notSubmitted, count(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 
else null end) AS submitted, count(*) AS totalApplications, 
count(case when (IS_QUERIED = true) then 1 else null end) AS queried, 
count(case when (APPROVED = true) then 1 else null end) AS approved, 
count(case when (APPROVED = false) then 1 else null end) AS notApproved  
FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS a LEFT JOIN PAYMENT_HISTORY b ON a.id=b.RECORD_ID 
AND b.PROCESS_TYPE_FK = a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK LEFT JOIN COMPANY c ON 
c.id= a.COMPANY_FK WHERE (c.COMPANY_TYPE_FK=:companyTypeId OR :companyTypeId=0) AND a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK in (9542,9594,9598) ", nativeQuery = true)

    AnnualReturnInterface countAnnualReturnByAllProcessTypeAndOrCompanyType(@Param("companyTypeId") Long companyTypeId);
    }
```

And the second controller is as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/count-all")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> countAnnualReturnRecordsByAllProcessType
(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

        Long companyType = searcherDto.getCompanyTypeId();
        AnnualReturnInterface annualReturnInterface = annualReturnRepository
                .countAnnualReturnByAllProcessTypeAndOrCompanyType(companyType);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", annualReturnInterface));
    }
```

So far so good, my code is now working on postgreSQL but with a different design compared to MS SQL.

Thanks to all who gave the question a shot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use @Convert in each attribute which you want to fix ,
2. Pass custom class to
   @Convert(converter=CustomConverter.class)
3. Than CustomConverter should implement AttributeConverter of  javax
4. Write your custom logic .

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the `LocalDateTime`. Your driver doesn't know how to handle it and is probably using default Java serialization to convert it to a `bytea` (which doesn't compare to a `bigint`).

The simplest solution (as you're already using native queries instead of JPA) is to convert it yourself. Only you know how you're supposed to do this (an epochtime? seconds or millis? what timezone?) but something like:

```java
long startValue = start.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond();
```

More advanced configuration would involve registering the correct converters. Again, there won't be one out-of-the-box because there's no defined way to get an integer from a local datetime.

I recommend you use a fully-specified type instead (`OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant`), and use proper datetime types in your schema.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. My question now is what about in other controllers where I am not using or posting any LocalDateTIme along with the other Long parameters in my request but they still throw the same error. And then conversely, there are many other places where I use the LocalDateTime and it works. What would you suggest could be the cause for this behavior and how do I fix those ones too? @OrangeDog

Comment: @kingified Then you haven't provided enough information in the question. Log the actual SQL and find the bytea.

Comment: I have updated my question to provide more details on the other controller that throws a similar error. Please check it out. And please explain more how I can log the actual sql and find the bytea. I will appreciate more details on that too please. Thanks

Comment: The used JDBC driver version can absolutely handle `LocalDateTime` through `PreparedStatement.setObject()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to this, but it will not have an actual fix, unless the PostgreSQL team decides to create a deferred type-check in their parser for when a null is passed on the initial go.

The workaround is thus...

```
private static final Long LONG_CONST = 0L;
@PostMapping("/date-sum")
public ResponseEntity<Object> sumRecordsWithDate(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

    Long type = searcherDto.getCompanyTypeId();
    Long process = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk();
    Long process1 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk1();
    Long process2 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk2();
    Long process3 = searcherDto.getProcessTypeFk3();
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getStartDate()), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getEndDate()), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));

    // difference starts here
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(..., ReturnType.class);
    // or createNamedQuery if you've registered it via NamedNativeQuery, which I recommend
    q.setParameter("processTypeFk", LONG_CONST).setParameter("processTypeFk", process);
    q.setParameter("processTypeFk1", LONG_CONST).setParameter("processTypeFk1", process1);
    q.setParameter("processTypeFk2", LONG_CONST).setParameter("processTypeFk2", process2);
    q.setParameter("processTypeFk3", LONG_CONST).setParameter("processTypeFk3", process3);
    q.setParameter("companyTypeId", LONG_CONST).setParameter("companyTypeId", companyTypeId)
    // these are never null, so we don't need to type-set them.
    q.setParameter("startDate", start);
    q.setParameter("endDate", end);

    ... q.getResultList();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", sumInterface));
}
```

What is happening here is with the first call to `setParameter` you are using a non-null value to make sure Hibernate correctly determines the type for that parameter, then with the second call you are setting the correct (and potentially null) value, but the type-check is already done, so it is skipped.

Comment: please do I make any changes to my repository interface (as stated in the question above) where I used native sql queries? @coladict

Comment: You avoid the repository interface entirely by going to the EntityManager directly.

Comment: This line is not compiling :         EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
It tells me "java: package sun.reflect.generics.tree does not exist"

Comment: I haven't used Spring-boot, so I don't exactly know where to get the EntityManager from. This was just short-hand for "you need the EntityManager for the request/thread". Maybe this will help https://www.netsurfingzone.com/jpa/how-to-get-jpa-entitymanager-in-spring-boot/

Comment: the error is actually coming from :

 Query q = em.createNativeQuery(..., ReturnType.class);

because it says  "java: package sun.reflect.generics.tree does not exist"... and this is the package that was imported by ReturnType.class...
import sun.reflect.generics.tree.ReturnType;

Comment: I merely added `ReturnType` as the entity type that you're trying to get. Replace it with your entity type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223986/discussion-between-kingified-and-coladict).

Comment: The response from the query is coming as null when it actually ought to return values from the db. Please see the detailed problem description here. I will appreciate your response please. @coladict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660717/how-to-use-jpa-native-query-and-typedparametervalue-to-perform-count